# ID tag link not working

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink

My website: cultpops.com

I'm trying to get the top left logo on my site to link to the 'about' portion on my page. As per another stackoverflow topic, I placed `[a href="#about"][/a]` around said logo and `[a id="about"][/a]` around said portion. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and CSS as your website may change in the future and make this question + answer useless.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this, but what would be the relevant html in this case other than the above code? Using wordpress fwiw.

Comment: For instance when you speak about `said logo`. Also, you refer to another SO topic, maybe you could link that so we have as much info as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you really put `[a id=”about”]` in your code. This is not an html tag. html tags always are like this `<htmltag>` and not with square brackets

If you want to link to an anchor you just need to give an id to the html element you want (doesn't have to be an `<a>` tag).

The easiest way to do this is for example on the image above your about section.

Set your editor to text instead of visual and add an id to your image or the a tag around it. It will look like this.

```
<a href="http://www.cultpops.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/logo21.png" id="about">
  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-97" src="http://www.cultpops.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/logo21.png" alt="logo2" width="97" height="133">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following around the "img src="example.com/image.png" tag:

```
<a href="http://example.com/youraboutpage">
<img src="example.com/image.png">
</a>
```

I can see you are using wordpress -the logo image tag is in your header.php file available in Appearance>Editor

Hope this helps

Admin Alex